# Recreation of a wordpuzzle game

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop, boolean

I am trying to code a wordpuzzle game, this is a snippet of the code I am stuck on, I feel like I have tried everything.

answers are a list of the words that are available to be found in the puzzle and their coordinates and the directions they are in. The answers present here are a snippet for testing purposes. What seems to happen is that program will find a word and say "this is working", but at the same time say "it is not a word", i dont know how to pass this.

The program prints the available answers after each round for testing purposes.

```
answers=[(2, 12, 'up', 'reduce'), (11, 0, 'left', 'cherimolla'), (7, 12, 'up', 'leopardbane'), (9, 12, 'upleft', 'bionomical')]
guess = []
move = False

players=[]
players.append("Stephan")

 while True:
    print(answers)
    for i in players:
      guess=input("Player " + str(i) + "'s name: make a guess:")
      guesses=guess.split(",")   
      for i in range(0,len(answers)-1):
        ans = answers[i]     
        if int(ans[0]) == int(guesses[0]) and int(ans[1])==int(guesses[1]) and guesses[2] in ans[2]:
          answers.remove(ans)
          
          print("this is working")
        if (int(ans[0]) != int(guesses[0]) and int(ans[1])!=int(guesses[1]) and ans[2]!=guesses[2] and i==len(answers)-1):
          print("sorry this is not a word")
```

Comment: Why have you mentioned ```range(0,len(answers)-1)```? range(0,n) returns 0 to n-1. I think you can use ```range(0,len)```

Comment: Use an `else` instead of the 2nd `if` statement. Alternatively, you can replace all the `and`s in the 2nd `if` with `or`s (De Morgan's laws: the opposite of `a and b` is `not a or not b`, and not `not a and not b`)

Comment: Also, removing from a list while looping over it is a very bad idea. In this case it shouldn't matter (because at most one answer should match the guess), but in general, when modifying a list, loop over a copy of it.

Comment: @ram I added the -1 as it runs into a error of listindex out of bounds

Comment: @koorkevani thank you I did that, it still prints the sorry not a word more than once, I only want it to print once, thats why I added the i==len(answers)-1

Comment: The 'out of bounds' happen because you remove from the list while looping (e.g you try to access the 4th element, but after you've removed there are only 3 left). But what if the guess matches the last answer in the list? if you do -1 it will never reach it! Told ya modifying while looping is evil lol. Easiest fix: `break` right after removing, to make it stop searching.

Comment: If the guess matches the 3rd answer, do you want it to print `"sorry", "sorry", "working", "sorry"`? Or do you just want it to print `"working"` once if anything matched and `"sorry"` once if nothing did?

Comment: @koorkevani the latter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After considering the discussion in the comments and making a few changes of my own, here's the code I came up with:

```py
answers = [
    (2, 12, 'up', 'reduce'),
    (11, 0, 'left', 'cherimolla'),
    (7, 12, 'up', 'leopardbane'),
    (9, 12, 'upleft', 'bionomical')]

players = ["Tom", "Jerry"]

# Index of the current player in the players list
player_index = 0

# While not all answers were guessed
while len(answers) > 0:
    # Ask for a guess
    player_name = players[player_index]
    guess_raw = input(player_name + ", make a guess (x,y,direction,word): ")
    guess = guess_raw.split(",")

    # Transform the guess into a tuple of the same format as the answers
    guess_tuple = (int(guess[0]), int(guess[1]), guess[2], guess[3])

    # Check if the guess is correct
    if guess_tuple in answers:
        print("Success!")
        answers.remove(guess_tuple)
    else:
        print("Failure")

    # Go to the next player
    player_index = (player_index + 1) % len(players)
```

And here's an example game:

```
Tom, make a guess (x,y,direction,word): 2,12,up,reduce
Success!
Jerry, make a guess (x,y,direction,word): 2,12,up,reduce
Failure
Tom, make a guess (x,y,direction,word): 11,0,left,cherimolla
Success!
Jerry, make a guess (x,y,direction,word): 7,12,up,leopardbane
Success!
Tom, make a guess (x,y,direction,word): 9,12,upleft,bionomical
Success!
```

Why the `player_index` shenanigans, instead of just looping over the players? Because otherwise, after Tom had guessed the last word, it still would've prompted Jerry for a guess, because the loop over the players wouldn't have ended yet.

Comment: Thank you! The player is not to guess the word, only the direction and coords, then check to see the word in the list.